# Linking intel TBB with Qt (compiler MSVC)

Tags: qt, tbb

Seeking for help with linking intel TBB and Qt **compiling with MSVC**. I don't have any problems when using Visual Studio and linking there, but Qt redflags errors in profiling file as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.1.1\include\oneapi\tbb\profiling.h(229): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.1.1\include\oneapi\tbb\profiling.h(229): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.1.1\include\oneapi\tbb\profiling.h(231): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.1.1\include\oneapi\tbb\profiling.h(231): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

My guess it's just qmake options problem, I've searched everywhere to find proper instructions how to link with Qt and couldn't find any.
My .pro file:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
#TBB
INCLUDEPATH += 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.1.1\include'
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/tbb/2021.1.1/lib/intel64/vc_mt/' -ltbb
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/tbb/2021.1.1/lib/intel64/vc_mt/' -ltbb_debug

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/tbb/2021.1.1/lib/intel64/vc_mt'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/tbb/2021.1.1/lib/intel64/vc_mt'
```

and main:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <oneapi/tbb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It was a bug in some qt versions. Moc(Meta-Object Compiler) has a different behavior. Maybe you can try downgrading Qt versions. Which version are you using now? Check this [qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80578)

Comment: @Ceopee, it's Qt 5.15.1. Thank you, I'll check it out.